# Store table row acces from web service in other table

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, web-services, analytics

i am trying to find information about the following. I have a table with CD Music information and a unique id and my web service (C# in VS) access the row information of that table. Now i would like to store in another table when and what unique id was requested from the web service (JSON) call. Who can point me to some good information? I looked into triggers but they don't do the job in sql since the only detect Update, Delete or Inserts and in my case the information is only accessed and not changed so now i was thinking perhaps i can do this in the web service call.

Example:
Read information on ID from table CD and store ID in table CD-ACCESS with the date and time.

Comment: thanks, i am not sure, since i am not changing any data, i just want to know and store what table row was accessed from the CD table. basically i just want to make some sort of custom analytics on that table to find out the most popular cd's and use that information further on on the website.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest letting the database or the db layer do the access tracking. Since you are using sql-server i suggest using stored procedures for the read accesses. There you can do whatever you want to keep track of what is happening (without having to connect or at least communicate with your database again from your web service).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stpReadInformation] 
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @readId int;

SELECT @readId = SELECT Id FROM tabCdInfos WHERE ....

INSERT INTO tabCdAccesses
@readId, GETDATE(), <UserInfo>, ...

SELECT @readId;
END
```

you can do this transactional if needed.

Here is an example to access stored proc via ado.net

```
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
        {
            con.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(<NameOfStoredProcedure>, con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", DbType.String).Value = <yourParamValue>;
            var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                return new YourDataModel(
                    rdr.GetGuid(0),
                    rdr.GetInt32(1)
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: that sounds like a good plan and for sure will improve performance, would you happen to have some more information on the subject?

Comment: Since i have no information how your database access looks like at the moment, it is hard for me to give you some concrete example or help.

By looking at your post i guess you are using a DataTable, which is filled by an SqlDataAdapter. You give this DataTable to your WebService and access the rows you need.

I suggest to not transfer the data table and instead use a data transfer object, which means a new class holding all the information and properties you need from the data table.

Comment: added an example for stored proc access by code (without entity framework).